# How to recover partition when uninstalling wubi?

Tags: windows-7, wubi, uninstall, partitioning

I have uninstalled wubi on my laptop, the problem is, my Hard Disk space wasn't restored. It went from 500gb to 250gb when I installed wubi, but when I uninstalled wubi/ubuntu, my hard disk space is still 250gb. So how do I recover the partition that I alloted upon installation of wubi?

Comment: you want all data ?

Comment: Just the space, I've already back-up my data that I used when I still needed ubuntu.

Comment: recover it from win 7 or using gparted

Answer (score 0):

Wubi does not create an actual partition, it installs into a file on your pre-existing partition. Look for it in `c:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` (assuming you installed it on drive c).

Comment: If that's the case, how could I recover the HD space that was lost when wubi was installed?

Comment: You need to delete the files under `c:\ubuntu\disks`.